# Who's this lady in the war room?

Tags: character, game-of-thrones

In S08E02, while the war room scene, I noticed a lady being present, standing between Theon and Brienne. Her face seems familiar, but can't see to recall who she is.

Apparently she is important enough to have a place in the war room.

[image]

Comment: I had this same question. At first because of the poor lighting I thought it was Yara Grayjoy which was _very_ confusing, it took a second viewing to realize and remember who it was.

Answer (score 48):

That is [Alys Karstark](https://gameofthrones.fandom.com/wiki/Alys_Karstark). She was introduced in the episode after Battle of Bastards where Jon Snow pardons her and [Ned Umber](https://gameofthrones.fandom.com/wiki/Ned_Umber).

Answer (score 9):

That is Alys Karstark. She is the head of the house Karstark after her father's execution at the hands of Robb Stark and her brother's death at the battle of the bastards. She has pledged her house to Jon Snow.

Here's a nice Family tree.

[image: Karstark Family Tree]